# My Joi extended rule will not be executed till the core rules all are positive

Tags: javascript, joi

we extended Joi with the Joi.extend() function in order to have some custom validations. Unfortunately this extension only will be executed when every other core Joi rules are tested positive.

I don't want to post code for now, maybe there is a common solution for that, e.g. some kind of "setting" in Joi or a common fault in using the extend() function.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why is this an issue?

Comment: @Ankh: Because in the front end only the errors from the Joi core functions will be shown until they are solved. The errors from our custom rules should be shown, too, not only if the core rules are solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by executing the rules separately. We built a chain like this, where requireField is one of our custom rules:

```
const ConfSchema = Joi.customObject().keys({ ... core rules ...}).requireField(... custom rules ...);
```

Now we make it in to steps:

```
const ConfSchema = Joi.object().keys({ ... core rules ...});
const CustomConfSchema = Joi.customObject().requireField(... custom rules ...);
```